# Finding the position in a file serially where all numbers from a list have been found

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal

I may have worded this **Title** incorrectly - my apologies for that.
I have a (large) text file with columns of numbers. I can extract the column from the file on the command line. I want to pipe this column into a command where I give a list of number and it tells me at which (file) position the list is matched - meaning that all the numbers in the list have appeared at least once in the column.

So for example, my list has the following numbers **1 2 3**

And the extracted column is (note I have put in line numbers which are not there)...

```
line1: 1
line2: 2
line3: 2
line4: 1
line5: 3
line6: 3
line7: 2
```

So in this case, it should return **5** (= `line5`).

Another example for clarity....

A column I extract from file has the following sequence on newlines...

```
1 2 2 1 3 3 2 ...
```

And I need to print the line number where all numbers in my list have matched, my list is `1 2 3`. So in this case it should say line 5 at which point it has found all 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Give a minimal input and expected output for clear understanding.

Comment: And the above is not minimal?

Comment: You need to explain it better I guess :) May be with another example

Comment: How are the numbers `1 2 3` producing `5` i.e. line number 5 as you indicated?

Comment: That is the line number by which all list numbers 1, 2 and 3 have been found.

Comment: That sounds better, by the way the list `1 2 3` has to be sequential or can be in any order?

Comment: Are you going to feed the program the numbers you want to look for or do you expect the program to scan all the numbers and decide on that?

Comment: Good questions, in my case luckily, the list can be specified by a single constant, i.e. a list length. So if the length is 10 items long, the list will contain `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. But it would also be nice if I can specify any list, e.g. `2 4 6`. I guess the list can be specified using a file in the latter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My data is exactly as above:

```
$ head -2 foo
line1: 1
line2: 2
```

In awk. Go thru every line and rememder the last line with a new number. Print it in the end:

```
$ awk '
!($2 in a) {  # if the value has not been seen before
    a[$2];    # remember it in array a
    i=NR}     # also remember the number of record (NR) with unseen data
END {         # in the end
    print i   # print the i from above
}' foo
5
```

If the file only has numbers, not `line1:` etc. change `$2`to `$1`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to feed the program the numbers you want to find, use this:

```
$ awk -v these="1 2 3" '  # pass the numbers to the program in variable
BEGIN {
    split(these,a," ")    # split them to a array
} 
($2 in a) {               # if found number is in a
    i=NR;                 # remember the NR
    delete a[$2]          # delete entry from array a
} 
END { print i }           # in the end print the last found NR
' foo
5
```

It fails if not all of the numbers are found and prints the `NR` of last found number. It could probably be achieved with: `END { for (j in a) exit; print i}`.

Comment: Would you mind just to explain the syntax in a bit more detail, I can use this as a template for a lot more situations.

Comment: That's a great logic to adopt, was thinking & trying a more complex logic. But how do you manage, when the user doesn't want all unique entries in `$2`, but only a sub-set say `1 2` in which case it should return  line number `2`, but your logic will process until all unique entries are found?

Comment: Was thinking of a way to user input in a `bash` variable and splitting it in an array and checking if all elements are mapped before processing every new line

Comment: @JamesBrown, how can it be adapted to include a list of arbitrary numbers?

Comment: See my edit. Remember, there are no checks to see if the given numbers even exist in the file. That's why it prints out the NR of last found required number.